# How would you make a python shell in python?

Tags: python, shell

How would you make the IDLE shell, using nothing but Python code? Now, I understand the beggingins, like a simple exec(raw_input('>> ')), but how would you get if and else statments, or for and while loops to work?

> while 1==1:

is considered invalid syntax. How would you prevent that?

The suggested thread isn't nearly the same thing, as all of the answers but one answer how to run a python program from a python program. One of the answers points kinda of like what I'm asking, but it would still fail in an if and else statement, or a while or for loop.

Comment: What do you mean, `while 1==1:` is invalid syntax? It's perfectly fine. Did you forget to put in a loop body when you tried it out?

Comment: If I had to make the IDLE shell in Python it would probably look something like this https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Lib/idlelib

Comment: @user2357112 I mean that if my code was exec('while 1==1:'), it would raise an error. That means that when making the shell, I cant just have it execute raw input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source code for IDLE is in the Python standard library, under the `idlelib` package. You can [look at the source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/idlelib) to see how they implement everything.

`idlelib` is a lot of code, so it might be overwhelming to try to go through it. The [`code` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/code.html) provides a Python implementation of Python's interactive mode; you could go through the [source code for that](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/code.py) to get an idea of how you could do things.